# On which node smart contract get executed

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, contract-invocation, evm

I have a general question in my mind please do correct me if i am thinking wrong .

Suppose if i deploy the smart contract on the ethereum blockchain having a functionality to pay some tokens at particular timestamp. Then on which node's evm that smart contract get executed how it get decided ? and my node is not any more connected to the network at the same time . Is this node selected by network randomly or their is any other algorithm or paradigm exists for this process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After you sign your transaction, it is broadcast onto the Ethereum network. Even if you go offline, the transaction is still being bounced around on various nodes. Nodes that are mining may choose to include your transaction in a block; any node wishing to include your transaction in the block must execute it.

Otherwise, your transaction will be executed on all nodes after it is incorporated into a block by a miner. The reason why all nodes execute the transaction even after it's included in a block is so that they can update the blockchain state. Also, it prevents the miner that included the transaction from cheating (e.g., by claiming the transaction consumed twice as much gas as it really did and then paying themselves the higher transaction fee).

Comment: i suppose this is not the answer of my question , i want to understand after the contract deployment a transaction generated by the contract itself not by any external call then the generation of transaction needed a environment for execution so where will be that environment or evm instance

Comment: A contract can't wake itself up later; it must be executed as part of a new transaction or a message call. A message call is basically a transaction initiated by another contract -- but that contract must have been started, at least indirectly, by a new transaction in the current block.